# Quotient group $G/H$ isomorphic to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was wondering if the following statement is true or not. Let $G$ a group and $H \triangleleft  G$

$$ G/H \cong G  \implies H = \left \{ 1 \right \}$$

I know it is true if $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130351/prove-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-can-not-be-isomorphic-to-a-proper-quot). Nevertheless, my intuition says it should be not true in the general case. Actually, I was trying to find a counterexample, taking G as a free group. However, I haven't found anything.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial). (Incidentally, taking $G$ as a finitely generated free group cannot work. One reason for this is because free groups are residually finite, and finitely generated, residually finite groups cannot have this property, by a [theorem of Mal'cev](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/672199/10513).)

Comment: Note, you say $N \triangleleft  G$ then use $H$...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let $G$ be the free group on countably many letters, and let $H$ be the normal subgroup generated by the first letter. Then $G/H$ is isomorphic to the free group on countably many letters, which is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: (of course, the natural map $G \to G/H$ will not be an isomorphism unless $H$ is trivial)

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample is given by the multiplicative group of the unit circle in the complex plane. The quotient by the subgroup $\{-1,1\}$ is isomorphic to the circle.